how to take screenshot as a texture or material.. at runtime
I’m making a slot based save system in unreal engine in which each slot has a screenshot indicating where the player left off.
I know render targets technically do the same thing but render targets are too heavy on the performance.
the second option is to use the log commands to take a screenshot but the problem is I don’t know to import it in realtime as a texture …

Any screenshot technique will be using a render target under the hood at some stage. Can you explain what profiling or other evidence is telling you this is "too heavy"? Try walking us through how you tried to implement it this way — that may help us spot places where there's avoidable overhead.

well, I didn't use it for this specific case I used it a realistic scape in which you could see the outer part and it had to be not zoomed in
the problem happend when I 1st spawned the 2d scene capture it cut my frames by 1/2 and sometimes even lower after a bit it becomes better but still there is a noticeable performance hit
that's why I don't want to use render target cause it's goning to spawn and destroy 2d SC very often my ram and vram are going to scream

Update:
I found a node called "Take High Res Screenshots" and that I think is using the console command under the hood but it's outputting a value of type "Automation Editor Task Object Reference" and while it's compatible with the widget in brush image it sets it to the default value.

I found a plugin called File Helper Blueprint Library (also available via Github) which has a couple nodes one of them is taking screenshots in real-time and it outputs texture 2D as well as the image path.

This answer would be even better if you showed how you used this to solve your problem. That way, future readers struggling with a similar issue can learn from your example.

oh it's pretty self-explanatory just a node provided by a plugin
